# Device camera data (not images but actual camera properties)

Tags: ios, swift, camera

I need access to my devices camera data (not image data! Already have that). Such as, "pinhole" fx & fy & anything else I can possibly get.

Currently, I'm using AVFoundation's 'AVCaptureSession' with a custom UI. But previously I used 'UIImagePickerController' which has a delegate method called

```
imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any])
```

I was able to retrieve the taken photograph from the "info" dictionary. It also gave me very detailed information regarding the camera & its capabilities. As it stands, I don't know how to retrieve this same detailed information during 'AVCaptureSession' photography. Please help

Comment: Have you setup a AVCapturePhotoCaptureDelegate class?

Comment: Nope. Didn't even know about it until you mentioned it

Comment: How are you saving your images then, if you are using the AVFoundation? At some point you have to call AVCapturePhotoOutput.capturePhoto(with:AVCapturePhotoSettings, delegate: AVCapturePhotoCaptureDelegate).

Comment: I use 'AVCaptureStillImageOutput' & call method "captureStillImageAsynchronously()". It returns a buffer of data which I capture with 'jpegStillImageNSDataRepresentation' method & then load it into a UIImage object. Viola. By the way, I don't save my image to anything; it is directly passed to a server for processing

Comment: You know that is deprecated? Checkout the AVCam Apple sample for how to use AVCapturePhotoOutput and a AVCapturePhotoCaptureDelegate. You can capture all the image exif data within the AVCapturePhotoCaptureDelegate class.

Comment: Snap. Wasn't paying attention. Could you write up some basic process answer so I can vote for it?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/157832/discussion-between-spads-and-krekin).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use AVCapturePhotoOutput and not AVCaptureStillImageOutput.

First the code below needs the following variables in your class

```
private let photoOutput = AVCapturePhotoOutput()
private var inProgressPhotoCaptureDelegates = [Int64 : AVPhotoCaptureDelegate]()
private let sessionQueue = DispatchQueue(label: "session queue", attributes: [], target: nil) // Communicate with the session     
private var videoDeviceOrientation : AVCaptureVideoOrientation = .portrait // this needs updated as the device orientation changes
```

Add photo output at AVSession setup

```
// Add photo output.
if session.canAddOutput(photoOutput) {
    session.addOutput(photoOutput)

    self.photoOutput.isHighResolutionCaptureEnabled = true
}
```

Your capturePhoto() function should be setup as follows

```
func capturePhoto(aspectRatio : Float, metaData : NSDictionary?) {
    sessionQueue.async {
        // Update the photo output's connection to match the video orientation of the video preview layer.
        if let photoOutputConnection = self.photoOutput.connection(with: AVMediaType.video) {
            photoOutputConnection.videoOrientation = self.videoDeviceOrientation
        }

        // Capture a JPEG photo with flash set to off and high resolution photo enabled.
        let photoSettings = AVCapturePhotoSettings()
        photoSettings.flashMode = .off
        photoSettings.isHighResolutionPhotoEnabled = true
        if photoSettings.availablePreviewPhotoPixelFormatTypes.count > 0 {
            photoSettings.previewPhotoFormat = [kCVPixelBufferPixelFormatTypeKey as String : photoSettings.availablePreviewPhotoPixelFormatTypes.first!]
        }

        // Use a separate object for the photo capture delegate to isolate each capture life cycle.
        let photoCaptureDelegate = MyAVPhotoCaptureDelegate(completed: { [unowned self] photoCaptureDelegate in
            // When the capture is complete, remove a reference to the photo capture delegate so it can be deallocated.
            self.sessionQueue.async { [unowned self] in
                self.inProgressPhotoCaptureDelegates[photoCaptureDelegate.requestedPhotoSettings.uniqueID] = nil
            }
        )

        /*
         The Photo Output keeps a weak reference to the photo capture delegate so
         we store it in an array to maintain a strong reference to this object
         until the capture is completed.
         */
        self.inProgressPhotoCaptureDelegates[photoCaptureDelegate.requestedPhotoSettings.uniqueID] = photoCaptureDelegate
        self.photoOutput.capturePhoto(with: photoSettings, delegate: photoCaptureDelegate)
    }
}
```

The MyAVPhotoCaptureDelegate class referenced in the capturePhoto() function above will need to be setup as follows

```
class MyAVPhotoCaptureDelegate: NSObject, AVCapturePhotoCaptureDelegate {

    init(completed: @escaping (AVPhotoCaptureDelegate) -> ()) {
        self.completed = completed
    }

    private func didFinish() {
        completed(self)
    }

    func photoOutput(_ captureOutput: AVCapturePhotoOutput, willCapturePhotoFor resolvedSettings: AVCaptureResolvedPhotoSettings) {
    }

    func photoOutput(_ captureOutput: AVCapturePhotoOutput, didFinishProcessingPhoto photoSampleBuffer: CMSampleBuffer?, previewPhoto previewPhotoSampleBuffer: CMSampleBuffer?, resolvedSettings: AVCaptureResolvedPhotoSettings, bracketSettings: AVCaptureBracketedStillImageSettings?, error: Error?) {
        if let photoSampleBuffer = photoSampleBuffer {
            let propertiesDictionary = NSMutableDictionary()

            if let exif = CMGetAttachment(photoSampleBuffer, kCGImagePropertyExifDictionary as NSString, nil) {
                if let exifDictionary = exif as? NSMutableDictionary {
                // view exif data
                }
            }

            photoData = AVCapturePhotoOutput.jpegPhotoDataRepresentation(forJPEGSampleBuffer: photoSampleBuffer, previewPhotoSampleBuffer: previewPhotoSampleBuffer)
        }
        else {
            print("Error capturing photo: \(String(describing:error))")
            return
        }
    }

    func photoOutput(_ captureOutput: AVCapturePhotoOutput, didFinishCaptureFor resolvedSettings: AVCaptureResolvedPhotoSettings, error: Error?) {

        // Use PHPhotoLibrary to save photoData to photo library
        ...
    }

    private let completed : (MyAVPhotoCaptureDelegate) -> ()
}
```

Most of this code comes from my version of AVCam with the specifics of my implementation removed. I have left out the code for saving to the photo library but you can extract that from the sample code. You can view the exif data at the point I have commented "view exif data"

Comment: Just noticed the photoOutput function I use has been deprecated. I guess I'll have to revisit this myself. I guess you would use func photoOutput(_ output: AVCapturePhotoOutput, didFinishProcessingPhoto photo: AVCapturePhoto, error: Error?) to catch the exif data